# Schipol to Keukenhof by public transport

Tags: budget, public-transport, netherlands, ams

How can I get (cheapest way) from Schipol to Keukenhof Garden by public transportation? I'm trying to understand if it's interesting buy the ticket with transport (25EUR) from the website, or if it's better I buy a ticket and go with public transportation.

Comment: Note that the Keukenhof is not in Amsterdam and is only open for a few months every year. You might want to peruse the official site or look up earlier questions on this site for more info.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The go-to site for public transports in the Netherlands is [9292.nl](http://9292.nl/en). You can enter two addresses but it also knows major sights and attractions so in this case you can look for “Schiphol” and “Keukenhof” directly.

Bus 858 is direct and should cost €4.69 (with a pay-as-you-go *OV-chipkaart* which costs extra if you don't already have it). Depending on the time and date, the connections vary a little but I don't think any other means of transportation is cheaper.

The [official site](http://www.keukenhof.nl/en/plan-your-visit/public-transport/) confirms this and also mentions a “Combi-Ticket” (transport and entrance) that could be easier and cheaper if that's the only thing you do in the Netherlands.

---

Since you are trying to see how the different solutions compare, let's look at the details:

- €16 for the entrance plus €4.69 bus fare each way makes a total of €25.38 so the €23.50 Combi-Ticket actually saves you money. But stay put, it doesn't end there.
- Additionally, the €4.69 fare is for *OV-chipkaart* users but the card itself costs €7.50, a very bad deal if you have no other use for it. If you don't have a regular *OV-chipkaart* and won't stay in the Netherlands, you need to buy a single ticket to the driver, which is more expensive.
- Bus 858 is not a regular line and I think it's what they call “Keukenhof express”. The info I could find is not very clear but it seems there is a special [“Keukenhof retour” fare for €10](http://www.arriva.nl/fileadmin/user_upload/Algemeen/2015/150126_prijslijst_losse_vervoerbewijzen.2015.pdf) which would save you some money compared to single tickets. But it's still €26 in total with the entrance ticket.
- The price of regular single tickets depends on the number of “zones” you cross. Between [Lisse and Schiphol on line 361](http://www.arriva.nl/fileadmin/user_upload/Algemeen/2015/141201_Routematrix_ZHN.pdf), there are 6 zones so, with Arriva (the operator of bus 858 and 361), a single ticket would cost you €6.50. The price for the Keukenhof entrance and two such tickets therefore work out to €29, a full €5.50 extra per person compared to the Combi-Ticket!

**It's a no brainer: Get the Combi-Ticket.** Before looking at the details, I would have guessed that you might be paying one or two euros more compared to the *OV-chipkaart* fare for the convenience (which would have been well worth it IMO) but you are actually saving money!

Comment: I'm trying to understand if it's interesting buy the ticket with transport (25EUR) from the website, or if it's better I buy a ticket and go with public transportation.

Comment: @MaxFerreira Is that the only thing you are going to be doing in the Netherlands? Are you coming regularly to the country?

Comment: [Bus 361 seems to be cheaper.](http://m.9292.nl/en/journeyadvice/station-schiphol/lisse_keukenhof/departure/2015-03-09T1004)

Comment: @JoErNanO It's based on the distance travelled so the 790m you walk at the end save you a few cents (and you could even step out before to save even more ;-). And the beauty of the system is that if you connect to bus 850 to end up at the same stop, you pay the exact same price than with bus 858. But the real price for tourists is higher, I will add some details.

Comment: You gotta love this obscure magic. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Amsterdam-Airport-AMS-Netherlands/Keukenhof) and [the 9292 journey planner](http://m.9292.nl/en/journeyadvice/station-schiphol/lisse_keukenhof/departure/2015-03-09T0934) both suggest a bus + feet combination, costing a total of 4.5`EUR`  according to the 9292 planner (the rome2rio price seems out of date).

The journey would be as follows:

> 1. Take bus 361 from Schiphol to Direction Noordwijk ZH
> 2. Get off at Lisse, Vreewijk bus stop
> 3. Walk to the gardens

Cheaper than this are walking and hitchhiking.

Comment: The price seems off. Better connections also exist.

Comment: I think I understood where Rome2Rio got it's price: It's a single ticket for 1-2 zones with Arriva (the operator of these busses). But there are 6 zones between Schiphol and Lisse.